# Grouping in extjs (with data in columns of group row)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have initial data with several columns. Some of positions have ParentID.

**Example of data:**

```
|  ID   | ParentID  |   Title   |    Info     |      Date     |
|-------|-----------|-----------|-------------|---------------|
|  101  |    Null   |  Title101 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|  102  |    Null   |  Title102 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|  103  |    101    |  Title103 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|  104  |    101    |  Title104 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|  105  |    101    |  Title105 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|  106  |    102    |  Title106 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|  107  |    Null   |  Title107 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
```

I need to form a grid with grouping by ParentID. But it the case of grouping in [sencha docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping.html) it doesn't show data in columns of group's row.
My expected result need to be like this (with data in columns of group row)

**Expected result:**

```
|   Title      |     Info    |   Date        |
|--------------|-------------|---------------|
| - Title101   |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|     Title103 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|     Title104 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|     Title105 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
| - Title102   |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|     Title106 |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
|   Title1017  |    text     |   01.01.1990  |
```

Does it possible in ext.js grid?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#tree-grid) example in the kitchen sink samples

Comment: @NAmorim True, In this case tree grid is what I need. Thank you so much. Plz duplicate your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Hey, no problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the expected result that you want, ExtJs has a nice [treepanel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html) component that displays data in a tree like structure. You just need to parse your data accordingly to the expected input for this component.

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    rootVisible: false,
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        // Store definition here
    }),
    columns: [
         {
            xtype: 'treecolumn', // Set this xtype here to display
            text: 'Title',       // data in this column as a tree  
            dataIndex: 'title',
            flex: 1
         }, 
         {
            text: 'Info',
            dataIndex: 'info',
            width: 100  
         },
         {
            text: 'Date',
            dataIndex: 'date',
            width: 100
         }
    ]
}
```

Here's an [example](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#tree-grid) from the Kitchen Sink samples.